# Making searchable UITableView that when a cell is selected it takes it to a different ViewController but the cell index is unchanged

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to make a `UITableView` that is searchable. However, when the new results load after a search, I want their original `indexPaths` to remain the same as they were before.

If I run my code right now, my first cell has an index of 0 and after I search for something and the number of cells that is returned is different, the index for the first cell is still 0.

Comment: Why was the code removed from the question?

Answer (score 0):

`ViewController` is obviously **not** the destination view controller in the storyboard.

Override `prepare(for segue`, pass the index path as `sender` and set the tag there, something like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotocompanyfav", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "gotocompanyfav" {
        let destinationController = segue.destination as! ViewController
        let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
        destinationController.searchStruct.buttonTag = indexPath.row
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer, however I don't  know what `ViewController` is

Comment: This isn't working for me. `ViewController` is a ViewController where the struct originates. I segue from `ViewController to my `secondViewController` (the desired destination from the `searchTableViewController`). When the view loads of the `secondViewController` I call the `ViewController.searchStruct.buttonTag` as an index for specific variables indicated in a dictionary. I want to call set this variable in the `searchTableViewController` as well so I can just perform a different segue to the same `secondViewController`. Updating the answer for these specifics would be much appreciated.